# Table is extending too far with long strings and won't go to new line

Tags: html, css

So I'm having a problem and I can't think of a fix for it.

Im dealing with a situation where users can post comments and it is displayed in a table. This table's width is set by **100%** and fits nicely with the **site's design**. However if users post a comment with words that have a lot of characters
`(ex: mynameisblahblahaaaaa!!!!!!!!!)`
 the table will extend over it's container to fit the long string.   With normal size words it just reaches the 100% width and goes down to a new line.

I realize I can do a fixed table width but that would involve using pixels and not a **%** but I feel using pixels would mess up the site on odd **dimension browsers**...

Is there anyway to fix this?

[Here](http://www.thoughtsmash.com/thought/193) is an example of what I'm talking about:

Comment: oh dear GOD NO Man!!  Not a partial table based layout... *sheds tear

Comment: advice... get rid of all tables.  Tables are meant for showing data, not meant for anything else.  Some might argue that comments are data, but I think you can do better using DIVS to display such things rather than a table.

Comment: I think you'll need to combine the first two answers given here: try using both `table-layout: fixed` and `word-wrap: break-word`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the CSS [`word-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/word-wrap) property set to `word-wrap: break-word` to instruct the browser to break in between words.

Also, don't use a table for what you're doing -- tables are intended only for tabular data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `table-layout:fixed` in you css